# I'm not able to check if file exist using shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I coded this for checking if maven exist and if not exist it download:

```
if [ ! -f /usr/share/maven ]
then
  echo "File does not exist."
  echo "Starting download maven"
  sudo apt-get install maven
else
  echo "Maven exist"
fi
```

But the script always try to download maven. So I t typed `whereis maven` to check where is maven and the output is:

```
maven: /etc/maven /usr/share/maven
```

I've also tried to use `/etc/maven` but the result is the same

Comment: You have a type in it? ```urs``` instead of ```usr```.

Comment: In the script I type usr and it dosen't work

Comment: Is ```/usr/share/maven``` a file or directory? Right now you check that it must be a file.

Comment: I'm an idiot. It's a directory so I've deleted -f and it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is /usr/share/maven a file or directory? Right now you check that it must be a file.

Use `if [ ! -d /usr/share/maven ]` instead if it's a folder.